# Object.values loses undefined properties

Tags: typescript

The following code obviously results in a runtime error:

```
type Foo = {
  x?: string | undefined
}
const foo: Foo = {
  x: undefined
}
const bar = Object.values(foo).map(x => x.toLowerCase())
```

However, according to Typescript, `Object.values(foo)` has a type of `string[]`. I explicitly added  `| undefined` to the type but it doesn't help. Now I have to find potential bugs all over my code. How do I get Typescript to do its job here?

Comment: The runtime error is a result of calling `.toLowerCase` on undefined, try `.map( x => x?.toLowerCase())` for a quick workaround.

Comment: That completely misses the point of the question. I specifically wrote this code to trigger the error to demonstrate the issue. The problem is that Typescript fails to detect the potential error. I added an extra field to a type that can be undefined, but I have to manually search the entire code base for places it might break.

Comment: This is [ms/TS#48587](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48587); you can either turn on `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` or work around it in some other way (make `x` required, widen `Object.values(foo)` to `Array<string | undefined>` manually, etc).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining (or find an appropriate dupe target).  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Actually there is a workaround of setting it as a non-optional property, fixing all issues with using it in the code, then set it back to optional. I forgot about `exactOptionalPropertyTypes`, but it's quite intrusive and will likely break a lot of other code (there's a reason it's not enabled by default), would be nice if there was a way to force it for individual types. Thanks for the link though, I couldn't find an issue on that somehow.

Comment: Could you please answer my questions so I can know how to proceed?

Comment: I guess I'm mostly wondering why `x?: string | undefined` has no effect without `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` flag - why else would someone write that, if not to imply that values can be undefined? I got what I wanted to know though, thanks (the issue link).

Comment: When `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` is disabled, `undefined` is automatically included in the domain of every optional property, so `{x?: string}` and `{x?: string | undefined}` are identical types in that case.  Similar to how `string` and `string | "a"` are the same type.  The desire to have `{x?: string}` and `{x?: string | undefined}` be different is what led to the existence of `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` in the first place. It's not clear how to have one without the other.

Comment: @riv: my bad, of course my comment misses the point, I incorrectly assumed it's just a simple runtime issue. Just a note - if `foo` is not assigned from a literal but comes from anywhere (a function call), it can contain other properties (not listed in `Foo` type) with `undefined` values. The `map` would completely miss these additional properties and their types while the `Object.values` will happily provide them.

Answer (score 1):

This is the subject of several GitHub issues, like [microsoft/TypeScript#48587](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48587), [microsoft/TypeScript#52045](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/52045), and [microsoft/TypeScript#56003](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56003).

---

Unless you enable [the `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#exact-optional-property-types---exactoptionalpropertytypes), TypeScript cannot tell the difference between a property that is missing and one that is present but `undefined`.  That is, `{x?: string | undefined}` and `{x?: string}` are identical types.

So `Object.values()` has to make an assumption: either treat `{x?: string}` as `{x?: string | undefined}`, or vice versa.  In [a comment on microsoft/TypeScript#44494](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44494#issuecomment-860264891), the language architect said:

> It's debatable what the correct behavior is, as `undefined` in the type of an optional property sometimes should be interpreted as "the property isn't there" and other times as "the property could be there with the value undefined". ... Our current behavior (stripping `undefined` from optional properties with inferring to an index signature) is likely the desired behavior most of the time, but strictly speaking it isn't sound--as illustrated by this issue.

So they decided to remove `undefined` form the domain in this case intentionally, even though there are some undesirable effects.  You might think this is irresponsible, but it's worse than that.  It actually turns out that `Object.values()` could potentially return *anything*, due to subtyping:

```
interface I { x: string }
interface J extends I { y: number }
const j: J = { x: "abc", y: 123 };
const i: I = j;
Object.values(i).map(x => x.toLowerCase()); // no error!!
```

Generally speaking TypeScript has to walk the line between soundness and usability; the only sound fix to `Object.values()` is to return `unknown[]`, but people would probably hate that, the way they hate `Object.keys()` returning `string[]`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#38520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38520) for the suggestion, though.

---

Anyway, back to missing-vs-`undefined`.  Most of the GitHub issues above about `Object.values()` not properly representing `undefined` have been closed with the advice to enable `--exactOptionalPropertyTypes`.  If you do that, it resolves the ambiguity between `{x?: string}` and `{x?: string | undefined}`, each of which behave correctly with `Object.values()`:

```
type Foo = { x?: string | undefined }
const foo: Foo = { x: undefined } // okay
const bar = Object.values(foo).map(x => x.toLowerCase()); // error

type Baz = { x?: string } 
const baz: Baz = { x: undefined } // error!
const qux = Object.values(baz).map(x => x.toLowerCase()); // okay
```

Obviously this change would have large effects throughout a code base, so you might decide to work around it in some other way (like widening `Object.values(foo) as (string | undefined)[]` or making `x` required in `Foo`, etc).  But that part is up to you.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQElUG9UA8BcqAzhDOAOaoC+oksiKqAUqlLtGACZEbaoCehMAFcAtgCNY1YEgD2YEqgBWhFgF4+BVACIE4pNoA0AwgEYATAGZqAbhnzFIQpg1K7AeXFKoSCADoANwQAG2EoIgAKEABKP1EEAAcI3FQ1AD48PwhZABlZAHdYAGEEIigI6OibVAB6GtQwWVYYGFkYAH4AQmBgCH4EtAAxWSaNHFx2whIyMEoAH1RhLig4cChOaTkFCFQ4EcJh0c1CJc4VtY2qWvrZAGsEfntt1HEEGFTUT29fQJCwyL2sli8SSKXSmWyeUKMBKZQqVWuzVaMB6fQGqAAQggAF4fcaTYikCibBw7V7YwhY3FjPAnZarMDraiI2DI7pbRQAR2EYM+Xh8-iCoXCEXJwMSyVSGVwWVyBWKpXKlWqdVQdwePWAQA)